# Trix formatting rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, trix

When users paste items from MS word, for example numbered list or bullet points Trix leaves the symbols in, but does not use the default stye rules. eg See below. **Note the indenting**
[image: Image showing incorrect formatting from pasting from word]

I am wanting to replace pasted bulletpoints with '`<li>`' tags since that is how the browser, or just adds the default style rules to the text.

---

As a workaround I was thinking that using Javascript/coffee script to replace all incidents of '•' to `<li>` during a paste command using `onPaste=''` However this is problematic, since the implementation could cause unforeseen effects.

---

Another way might be to create a regex expression, to remove the sybols and do It JIT while pasting.

Any other suggestions would be welcome in achieving this.

---

## Edit

```
/\d\.\s+|[a-z]\)\s+|•\s+|[A-Z]\.\s+|[IVX]+\.\s+[•].\s/g
```

This regex expression can find Numbered list and a simple replace on the pasted string, will allow for the desired results.

Comment: I think you should do it with custom javascript and regex. Similar request was reported in 2015 ([source](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/31#issuecomment-149351303)) and the solution was to implement this manually ([source](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/31#issuecomment-149476933))